# Looking for an concise expression that extracts values from results returned form Solve

Tags: equation-solving, core-language

I solved a linear system which returned:

```
{{A[0, 0] -> 0, A[0, 1] -> 0, A[0, 2] -> 1, A[0, 3] -> 4, 
  A[0, 4] -> 5, A[0, 5] -> 2, A[0, 6] -> 0, A[1, 0] -> 0, 
  A[1, 1] -> 10/3, A[1, 2] -> 10, A[1, 3] -> 20/3, A[1, 4] -> 0, 
  A[1, 5] -> 0, A[1, 6] -> 0, A[2, 0] -> 1, A[2, 1] -> 16/3, 
  A[2, 2] -> 10, A[2, 3] -> 20/3, A[2, 4] -> 0, A[2, 5] -> 0, 
  A[2, 6] -> 0, A[3, 0] -> 2, A[3, 1] -> 4, A[3, 2] -> 0, 
  A[3, 3] -> 0, A[3, 4] -> 0, A[3, 5] -> 0, A[3, 6] -> 0, 
  A[4, 0] -> 1, A[4, 1] -> 2, A[4, 2] -> 0, A[4, 3] -> 0, 
  A[4, 4] -> 0, A[4, 5] -> 0, A[4, 6] -> 0}}
```

Is it possible in one or two lines to create and assign directly thoose values to the variable `A[i,j]`?

I have read some questions about how to get values from solve but people often want to renames the variables or only extract a part of the solution so that's probably why the solution takes lines.

Isn't it possible to directly extract the answer in one simple line?

Answer (score 4):

```
rules = 
  {{A[0, 0] -> 0, A[0, 1] -> 0, A[0, 2] -> 1, A[0, 3] -> 4, 
    A[0, 4] -> 5, A[0, 5] -> 2, A[0, 6] -> 0, A[1, 0] -> 0, 
    A[1, 1] -> 10/3, A[1, 2] -> 10, A[1, 3] -> 20/3, A[1, 4] -> 0, 
    A[1, 5] -> 0, A[1, 6] -> 0, A[2, 0] -> 1, A[2, 1] -> 16/3, 
    A[2, 2] -> 10, A[2, 3] -> 20/3, A[2, 4] -> 0, A[2, 5] -> 0, 
    A[2, 6] -> 0, A[3, 0] -> 2, A[3, 1] -> 4, A[3, 2] -> 0, 
    A[3, 3] -> 0, A[3, 4] -> 0, A[3, 5] -> 0, A[3, 6] -> 0, 
    A[4, 0] -> 1, A[4, 1] -> 2, A[4, 2] -> 0, A[4, 3] -> 0, 
    A[4, 4] -> 0, A[4, 5] -> 0, A[4, 6] -> 0}};

Set @@@ rules[[1]];
Definition @ A
```

[image: definitions]

Comment: Rather than `Definition@A`, recommend `Array[A, {5, 7}, {0, 0}] // MatrixForm`